# Do you need to use __init__.py to import a class from a module within a package cleanly?

Tags: python, python-module

Say I have a src folder, and a package named Foo, with a module named Foo containing a class also named Foo. Then in the src folder I have a main module that wants to have the Foo class directly in its namespace.

```
-src
    -Foo
        __init__.py
        Foo.py
    main.py
```

I believe I could do something like this

main.py

```
from Foo.Foo import Foo
```

or add this to the packages init

```
import Foo
```

or

```
from Foo import Foo
```

then in main I could try

```
 from Foo import Foo
```

But ideally I would like to be able to just put

```
import Foo
```

in main.py and have that class available directly as Foo (not Foo.Foo)

Maybe its not a best practice to name a package, module, and class all the same, but it seems like I have run into situations where it does make sense. I also know I should probably make the module name all lowercase, but I kept it like that for this example.

Comment: There isn't any way to make `import Foo` import a class and not a module.  What you said in your last paragraph is on the right track.  Why do you feel you need a package for this?  If you just use a module then `from foomodule import Foo` is brief enough.

Comment: that makes sense. i guess it just seems like keeping things in packages is a neat idea.maybe i was thinking about a package where the class itself relies on other modules and maybe even sub packages within it, and being able to just get that class imported. for instance if i have a package for connecting to a db in sql alchemy, and the class uses models imported from modules within the package.

Comment: The more stuff you have in your package, the less sense it makes to have `import package` magically import just one of those things instead of importing the actual package.  If you need a package to hold multiple modules, great, but then you need to say which modules you want to import, or what stuff you want to import from each.  Just try doing it the normal Pythonic way with an appropriate naming scheme.  I think you'll find it's not actually that much of a hardship to do `from foomodule import Foo` once at the top of your program.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `__init__.py` to make a folder be recognized by Python as a module holding files or modules that can themselves be imported.  Thus,

- No, you technically don't need it to import a class--you could `from myfile import myclass`.
- However, given your structure, you do need to have `__init__.py` so that for modules outside of the `Foo` folder, it will be recognized as an importable module.

Comment: i understand what the file does and why its needed to make a package, it just feels like i should be able to get at the class easier if its inside a package and module.